# flowtype definition of Iterable from immutable.js breaks other libs' Iterables

Tags: react-native, immutable.js, flowtype

I just added immutable.js as a dependency to my project. I added

```
node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js.flow
```

to my `.flowconfig`.

The problem is that immutable exports an `Iterable` type, which is also a global type used in many other libraries that are in `node_modules/`, such as `fbjs` and `react-native`. For example one of the errors below.

```
node_modules/fbjs/lib/countDistinct.js.flow:22
22: function countDistinct<T1, T2>(iter: Iterable<T1>, selector: (item: T1) => T2): number {
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ type application of identifier `Iterable`. Too few type arguments. Expected at least 2
32: declare class Iterable<K, V> extends _ImmutableIterable<K, V, typeof KeyedIterable, typeof IndexedIterable, typeof SetIterable> {}
                        ^^^^ See type parameters of definition here. See lib: flow/immutable.js:32
```

In order to fix this I copied `immutable.js.flow` to my project and removed the `.flowconfig` line that includes it. In my copied file I rename Iterable to WhateverIterable and the errors are gone.

What is the best way to fix this thing without having to manually edit the immutable definitions?

Comment: adding `type Iterable<+T> = $Iterable<T,void,void>;` to my defs solved the issue. I copied the definition from flow core. Not sure what is the right way to do it though

Comment: The reason this helped was that using a declaration file as a library definition can accidentally declare some things as global which should just be local to a module. `immutable.js.flow` intends to declare `Iterable` inside the `immutable` module, but using it as a libdef declares `Iterable` globally, and overrides the builtin `Iterable` definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that `node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js.flow` is not written to be a library definition, so using it as one can cause errors.

## What is `immutable.js.flow`

The [docs](https://flowtype.org/docs/declarations.html#declaration-files) refer to these files as *declaration files*. `immutable.js.flow` sits next to a file named `immutable.js`. Whenever Flow is asked to require `immutable.js`, it will resolve to `immutable.js.flow` instead. You can test this with the `flow find-module` command, which shows which file Flow resolves to when `foo.js` imports `immutable`:

```
$ flow find-module immutable foo.js
/Users/glevi/test/immutable/node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js.flow
```

Declaration files are written a little differently than libdefs. Library definitions declare a bunch of global things. They declare which variables, functions, types, classes, modules, etc are available globally, and declare the types of these things. Declaration files declare only the type of the module that they are shadowing.

A libdef for immutablejs would look like

```
declare module 'immutable' {
  declare class Iterable<K,V> { ... }
  ...
}
```

while `immutable.js.flow` might look like

```
declare export class Iterable<K,V> { ... }
```

## What should you do

In theory, you should not need to add `node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js.flow` to your `.flowconfig`. Flow should automatically use it whenever your code imports `immutable`.

If there is a problem with the `immutable.js.flow` that immutable ships with, then the best thing to do is to open a pull request or issue against [immutable.js.flow](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/type-definitions/immutable.js.flow) or to submit a libdef to [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed).

A quick search shows someone [working on a immutable libdef](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/pull/401), so that might help too!